# Google Cloud Functions req/res with Promise by node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, google-cloud-functions, node-fetch

I am a total newbie to Javascript and trying to set up a bridge between two of the services I use. The goal is simply take body or the request, do a promise api call to another service to respond with the body of that api call. I have been able to take the body of the request and send it to the service, but I'm having trouble receiving that response and making body of that response as a response of the function. Please help me out. Thank you.

```
var moment = require('moment');
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

var unixtime = moment().unix();
var apiUser = process.env.apiUser;
var secret = process.env.apiKey;
var url = process.env.url;

exports.test = (req, res) => {
  var message = req.body;
  message = JSON.stringify(message);
  var body = "{\n    \"ops\": [{\n        \"conv_id\": \"679690\",\n        \"type\": \"create\",\n        \"obj\": \"task\",\n        \"data\": message\n    }]\n}\n"
  body = body.replace(/message/ig, message);
  var signature = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(CryptoJS.SHA1(unixtime + secret + body + secret));

  function request1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      var options = fetch(url+apiUser+'/'+unixtime+'/'+signature, {
          method: 'post',
          body: body,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      });

      options.then(res => {
          var result = res.json;
          console.log(result);
          resolve(result);
        })
        .catch(() => { // if .then fails
          console.log('Promise rejected');
          let rejectMessage = 'Sorry, an error occurred.';
          reject(rejectMessage); // Promise rejected
        });
    });
  }

  request1();
};
```

Comment: So you just want to send as a response `result` object (inside options promise)?

Comment: yes. more specifically result.body.ops.data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can retrieve `result` object easily because function `request1` returns a promise resolving that object, so this should work:

```
request1().then((resultObject)=>{
    //resultObject === result
    return res.send(resultObject);
});
```

Also, `res.json()` returns a promise, so you should do:

```
options.then(res => res.json()).then(result => {
          console.log(result);
          resolve(result);
        })
```

Comment: results in a timeout as it doesn't know what is `resultObject` - what goes there?

Comment: Sorry, if you want to send that object as a response you can use `return res.send(resultObject);`

Comment: so the output is empty, while with the current code it should be `json` as I have `console.log(result);` which logs `json`

Comment: thanks a lot man!!! worked like a charm! could you please also tell me where exactly in `res => res.json())` do I need to specify which part of the response body i want to return as a result? thank you

Comment: Yes, `res.json()` transforms the response of `fetch` function into a JSON object akynchrounsly, that's why you have to call `.then` once again.